# node.js + expressでreq.body要素を取得する時

Tags: javascript, node.js

node + express の際にputされたJson型のデータをreq.bodyから取得しログを出力しようとしているのですが

JSON.stringify(req.body)

とすると__prot__という要素が入ってしまいこれを削除またはデータに含めないようにするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify()`関数の第2引数を利用するのは如何でしょうか?

```
JSON.stringify(req.body, (key, value) => key === "__prot__" ? undefined : value)
```

参考: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify